# Java webapps security constraints & custom security providers

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm creating a restful web service using Resteasy.  One thing I need to do is to secure the service using a standard HTTP auth request.  The tricky part is that the service is multi-tenant and needs to use one of the path parameters to determine the security realm.

There are a lot of articles [typical of this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security) which describe setting up a single-tenant service.  What I can't find is what to configure, and what interfaces to implement to describe my own security which is based on a path parameter + the username in the HTTP authentication method.

I envision that prior to calling any of the application logic, tomcat/resteasy would call a SecurityProvider (or whatever) interface with the HttpServletRequest and have me either throw a 401 or return a SecurityContext that gets passed to the JAX-RS handlers.  In that routine, I would inspect the path parameters, and make a determination based on parameter+username+password given in the Basic/Digest/Form.

Is there any such beast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd update this since there's bee little activity on this question.

It looks like there's no baked in feature to do what I envisioned, so instead I extended the RestEasy servlet and added the security checks in my override before passing control back to the stock RestEasy servlet.

Seems to work well.